# Does HTML `autofocus` only work on a limited class of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, autofocus

I don't see any constraints listed at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus).

However, despite putting `autofocus` on the second list item in this code, the `document.activeElement` on page load is `<body>`:

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li id="two" tabindex="1" autofocus>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="button1">First button</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">Second button</button>
```

By contrast, placing `autofocus` (exclusively) on the second button (`button2`) does cause that to be the active element on page load.

So, does `autofocus` only work on certain elements?

Is the only way for the page to load with a focus on the second list element through

```
document.getElementById("two").focus();
```

Comment: `No more than one element in the document [...] may have the autofocus attribute.`

Comment: From [Document: activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)... _"Which elements are focusable varies depending on the platform and the browser's current configuration."_

Comment: @MisterJojo Now fixed. Testing was done with `autofocus` on one element only.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is more likely that the focusing steps are performed after the load event is fired.

The relevant specs are at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#flush-autofocus-candidates.

From this we can derive that for the `autofocus` attribute to do something at page load, we need:

- The document to be same-origin with the top-most document, i.e. not in a cross-origin iframe, and thus hard to show in an REPL here...
- The element to be a [focusable area](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area), otherwise the closest such focusable-area will be chosen.

If we assume you ran this code in its own page, then you met both conditions and it is supposed to work.

Now, if you do log the `activeElement` in the *load* event, you may be before the next [flush autofocus candidates](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:flush-autofocus-candidates) which happens during the [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps of the event-loop and is thus unrelated to the loading of the document. To be sure to run after that initial flush, you can use `requestAnimationFrame()` which will queue a callback to fire a bit after that step.

As for why you saw it work when only the `<button>` had the attribute, I guess it was just a fluke.

[Here I set up a glitch project](https://autofocus-timing.glitch.me/) demonstrating the issue, sometimes (needs a few refresh on my Chrome to meet it, Firefox reproes only on the initial navigation but not on refresh, and Safari reproes 100% of the time).

Comment: I've tried it multiple times. `autofocus` works as expected when attached to the second button and never works when attached to the second list element. As far as I can tell, the only way to focus the second list element is selecting it by script and using the `.focus()` method.

Comment: @zadrozny I have added a link to a glitch demo. From there I get the correct result in rAF from every browser on macOS. In load it's sporadic in Chrome, correct in Firefox and wrong in Safari.